# UIView resizing after rotation with CGAffineTransform view size is unpredictable

Tags: ios, uiview, cgaffinetransform, rotatetransform

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Weird behavior of UIView frame after rotation in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802830/weird-behavior-of-uiview-frame-after-rotation-in-iphone)

I am doing an app which has a feature to rotate and re size a view. i have  implemented this feature but i do face an issue.

**My problem**

The View wil be resized when dragging its four corners, after resizing it i can  rotate the view in both directions.

Once the rotation is done, if i try again to resize the view by dragging its corner, the view's size gone to unpredictable value and its moving all around the screen.

**Similar Problem**

I googled lot but i did not get any perfect answer. some people has asked same question but none of them get any good result. I spend lots of time on it but i could not solve it. please help me out
Following are the list of similar questions:

[similar question link : 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587168/uiview-resizing-after-rotation-with-cgaffinetransform)

[similar question link : 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8064089/applying-scaling-and-rotation-on-a-view-using-cgaffinetransform)

**My sample code**

[link](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/43007975/AEMobile%20App%20build%20Enterprise/sampleImgMve.zip)

**Code to resize the view**

**Touches Began method**

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

NSLog(@"[touch view]:::%@",[touch view]);

touchStart = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:testVw];
isResizingLR = (testVw.bounds.size.width - touchStart.x < kResizeThumbSize && testVw.bounds.size.height - touchStart.y < kResizeThumbSize);
isResizingUL = (touchStart.x <kResizeThumbSize && touchStart.y <kResizeThumbSize);
isResizingUR = (testVw.bounds.size.width-touchStart.x < kResizeThumbSize && touchStart.y<kResizeThumbSize);
isResizingLL = (touchStart.x <kResizeThumbSize && testVw.bounds.size.height -touchStart.y <kResizeThumbSize);    
}
```

**Touches Moved Method**

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
CGPoint touchPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:testVw];
CGPoint previous=[[touches anyObject]previousLocationInView:testVw];




float  deltaWidth = touchPoint.x-previous.x;
float  deltaHeight = touchPoint.y-previous.y;

NSLog(@"CVTM:%@",NSStringFromCGRect(testVw.frame));


if (isResizingLR) {
    testVw.frame = CGRectMake(testVw.frame.origin.x, testVw.frame.origin.y,touchPoint.x + deltaWidth, touchPoint.y + deltaWidth);
}  
if (isResizingUL) {
    testVw.frame = CGRectMake(testVw.frame.origin.x + deltaWidth, testVw.frame.origin.y + deltaHeight, testVw.frame.size.width - deltaWidth, testVw.frame.size.height - deltaHeight);
} 
if (isResizingUR) {
    testVw.frame = CGRectMake(testVw.frame.origin.x ,testVw.frame.origin.y + deltaHeight,  testVw.frame.size.width + deltaWidth, testVw.frame.size.height - deltaHeight);      
} 
if (isResizingLL) {
    testVw.frame = CGRectMake(testVw.frame.origin.x + deltaWidth ,testVw.frame.origin.y ,  testVw.frame.size.width - deltaWidth, testVw.frame.size.height + deltaHeight);   
}

if (!isResizingUL && !isResizingLR && !isResizingUR && !isResizingLL) {
    testVw.center = CGPointMake(testVw.center.x + touchPoint.x - touchStart.x,testVw.center.y + touchPoint.y - touchStart.y);
}

}
```

First Step before resizing [image]

Secondly i resize  and rotate it[image]

Thirdly i try to resize it but it shifts back to its original position [image]

These are the updated screens for your reference...

Comment: please post a small snippet of the code you are using to resize the view.  the full project is ok, but you should also post the code directly in your question, too.  thanks.

Comment: as to the problem, without seeing your code, I'd suggest [that you look here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5868620/119114).  if you're using the `frame` property at all after the rotation, that's probably the problem.

Comment: @Nate thanks for your response. i posted the code, please look on it

Comment: i set CGAffineTransformIdentity in touches began method, it can see some better result. but view is re setting back to its orignal position.. Pls find them in the added screenshots   testVw.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

Answer (score 5):

The `frame` property is undefined when `transform != CGAffineTransformIdentity`, as per the docs on `UIView`. That must be your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your response. i am not clearly understand your point. can you provide some sample code.

Comment: Check the answers to the question yours has been flagged a duplicate of.